# How to add additional information to Test Result Details

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have some basic unit tests in VS2010 that I'm currently running.  I'd like to be able to add some additional information to the Test Result Details screen (When a unit test completes, right click on it in the Test Results screen, and select Test Result Details).  Currently it just lists Common Results, and some standard information.

[image: Common Results]

Is there a way to include some additional values to test result?  For example, PreCleanup, initialization, Test, Post Cleanup, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, anything written to the `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` will be displayed on an Debug Trace Pane..

[image]

Comment: I typically use log4net in my code and then set up a DebugTraceAppender to show log output in the test result.